# Cananda Social Insurance Number Regex

Tags: regex

At the moment I'm having some issues with my Regex pattern for matching Cananda Social Insurance Numbers. At the moment my current regex looks like this,

```
"^\\d{3}\\s?\\d{3}\\s?\\d{3}$"
```

And it's returning results with the following patterns.

```
111-999-111
111999111
111 999 111
```

However, my issue arises when I want to include regex patterns for the below patterns as well.

```
111.999.111
111/999/111
```

Moving forward, are there any examples I should try to include this? I'll include my following attempts below which I've had no success with. And just a little background, I'm using Terraform to define my Regex pattern if that is of any help. Thanks!

```
"^(\\d{3}.\\d{3}.\\d{3})|(\\d{9})$"
"^\\d{3} \\d{3} \\d{3}|\\d{9}|\\d{3}.\\d{3}.\\d{3}|\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{3}|\\d{3}/\\d{3}/\\d{3}$"
```

Comment: How exactly is this related to [tag:terraform]?

Answer (score 1):

The following regex pattern will either match a string with 9 digits, or 3 groups of 3 digits seperated by one delimiter (space, dot, slash, dash)

```js
^\d{3}(?:\d{6}|([ .\/-])\d{3}\1\d{3})$
```

> `^` : start of line or string
> `\d{3}` : 3 digits
> `(?:` : start of non-capturing group
> `\d{6}` : 6 digits
> `|` : or
> `([ .\/-])` : capture group 1 for delimiter
> `\d{3}\1\d{3}` : 3 digits & reference to group 1 & 3 digits
> `)` : end of non-capturing group
> `$` : end of line or string

Test on regex101 [here](https://regex101.com/r/UtJnE8/1)